# Netlogo Procedure n-of 2 neighbors

Tags: command, netlogo, procedures

I am trying to write a procedure in Netlogo that first identifies two random neighbors of a red patch, and then changes the two patches to blue. The patches on the grid are either red, blue or white.

I put this code in the "to go" section and it invalidated the "tick". It also doesn't seem to run anywhere.

```
to run-2-neighbors-people
  if all-voters-talked-2-people
  [ ask n-of 2 neighbors with [ pcolor = red ]
    [ set pcolor blue]
   ]
  end
```

Here is the complete code:

```
patches-own
[
  vote   ;; my vote (0 or >= 1)
  total  ;; sum of votes around me
]

to setup

  clear-all
  ask n-of (percentage-of-voters / 100 * count patches) patches [
    set vote 1 ]
  ask patches [set-color]
  ask patches [set initial-voters count patches with [ pcolor = red ] ]
  ask patches [set non-voters count patches with [pcolor = white] ]

  reset-ticks

end


to go
   ask patches
    [ set total (sum [vote] of neighbors) ]
   ask patches [if pcolor = white
     [if total >= 4 [set pcolor blue ] ] ]
   ask patches [if pcolor = white
     [if total < 4 [ set vote 0 ] ] ]
   run-all-voters-talked-2-people
   run-share-on-social-media
  tick
end

to run-share-on-social-media
  if share-on-social-media
  [ask patches with [pcolor = red] [
      sprout 1 [
      set shape "arrow"]
       ]]
end

to run-all-voters-talked-2-people
   ask patches with [pcolor = red] [
  ask n-of 2 neighbors with [ pcolor = red ]
        [set pcolor blue] ]
end


to set-color  ;; patch color procedure
  ifelse vote >= 1
    [ set pcolor red ]
    [ set pcolor white ]
end
```

Comment: what does "it invalidated the 'tick'" mean?

Comment: @SethTisue it probably means that when he added this code the program didn't ticked and that's probably because it fails to terminate.

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code, for example what does `all-voters-talked-2-people` procedure do?

Answer (score 1):

What about this? It works fine until all neighbors of red patch become blue. You just need to add button "setup" and "go" to your interface.

**MODIFIED:**

in this example, the red patch firstly check the color of its neighbors and only IF there are more or equal 2 with white color, then it turns random 2 of them into blue. ELSE (from "`ifelse`"not enough white neighbors), nothing happens.

In this approach you will not have this warning: `Requested 2 random agents from a set of only 1 agents.`

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks  ; add reset ticks in "setup" - without this you can't use "tick" in "go" procedure
  setup-patches  
end

to setup-patches
  ; create random world with 3 basic colors
  ask patches [
    set pcolor white
  ]
  ask n-of floor (count patches / 3) patches [
    set pcolor blue 
  ]
  ask n-of 5 patches with [pcolor = white] [
    set pcolor red 
  ]
end

to go
  ask patches with [pcolor = red] [
    ; turn white patches to blue only if the red patch has at least 2 neighbors with pcolor white.
    ; if there is only 1 neighbor with pcolor white, nothing happens 
    ifelse count neighbors with [pcolor = white] >= 2 
       [ ask n-of 2 neighbors with [pcolor = white] [
           set pcolor blue 
       ]
       ]
       [ stop ]  
       ]
  tick  ; add tick at the end of "go" procedure
end
```

**3rd modification:**

if you are a patch and your color is red, then ask i) 2 of your neighbors (whatever neighbor, thus can be blue, white, red) to ii) turn blue if you are white. So, if these 2 neighbors from i)

- are both blue/red -> nothing happens.
- are both white -> both turn
- blue one white one different color -> only the white turn blue

The code:

```
to go
  ask patches with [pcolor = red] [
   ask n-of 2 neighbors [
      if pcolor = white [
        set pcolor blue 
      ]
    ]
  ] 
  tick 
 end
```

final state:

[image]

Comment: Now it is throwing this error message: Requested 2 random agents from a set of only 1 agents.
error while patch 12 -2 running N-OF
  called by procedure RUN-ALL-VOTERS-TALKED-2-PEOPLE
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'

Comment: I added the full code to my questions. Can anyone enlighten me here?

Comment: However, are you sure that it is not enough to convert at least one white patch to blue? do you need two of them at any time step?

Comment: I don't need 2 to *convert* 2, but at least ask two patches around it, if it's white, then to turn it bluet, but if it's red or blue then leave it alone.

Comment: the idea is that one patch (voter) communicates with 2 of its neighbors.